# How to combine mkdocs-materials and bootstrap 5 to work together

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-5, mkdocs, mkdocs-material

I have been learning both Material for MkDocs and Bootstrap 5 in unison. One day, I said, "Self, how come you can't take all of the features of Bootstrap 5 and make them available within Materials for Mkdocs?" So reading the documentation of Mkdocs and Material for Mkdocs and a few intelligent people's responses from Stackoverflow, I came up with this . . .

```
site_name: Discipleship28GO
site_url: https://discipleship28GO
nav:
   - Home: index.md
   - "Study Toolsets": studytoolsets.md
   - About: about.md
theme: 
   name: material
   custom_dir: overrides
   palette:
      primary:  deep purple
      scheme:  slate
markdown_extensions:
  - attr_list
  - md_in_html
plugins:
  - glightbox
extra_css:
  - stylesheets/extra.css
  
extra_javascript:
  - javascripts/extra.js
```

Notice under theme you see

```
   palette:
      primary:  deep purple
      scheme:  slate
```

Where scheme: slate gives you a nice grayish feel with the purple menu color.
[image]

So doing some more searching, I found that you could put a CDN link in the mkdocs.yml file as such:

```
extra_css:
 - stylesheets/extra.css
 - https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css

  
extra_javascript:
 - javascripts/extra.js
 - https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js
```

Thus here is the PROBLEM! The Bootstrap 5 CDN links OVERRIDE the Mkdocs-Materials theme settings as seen here,

[image]

I am sure that I can pick through some post and play around to stablize the Mkdocs-Materials theme to NOT be overrided, but my question is, has anyone figured out how to inject Bootstrap 5 cleanly and easily?